# Etymology of kato and kata

Tags: etymology, word-formation

According to [the Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/kato#Esperanto), *kato* originates from French, Italian, Latin, etc... and *kata* comes from *kato* + *a*. But how can we say that it is not the opposite? Can we say that the root *kat-* comes from French, Italian, Latin, etc... and depending on the suffix used, it defines the grammatical class of the word (like noun, adjective, ...)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Esperanto, the root words themselves already have a meaning. So the root *kat* is already the animal and it is intrinsically a noun. Similarly, the root *bel* intrinsically represents the state of something so it is most naturally used as an adjective.

However, neither of these roots can be used alone without an ending to classify it, so even though *kat* is a noun, you need to add the *-o* to use it in a sentence. And *bel* needs to have *-a* if it is used as an adjective. These endings don’t change the base meaning.

On the other hand, adding *-a* to *kat* changes the meaning to be “like a cat”. So in that sense, *kata* is a derived word from the Esperanto word *kato*. Adding *-a* to *bel* doesn’t create a new meaning, so we wouldn’t say that *bela* is derived from *belo*.

So, I guess you could say that *kato* is just a declination of the root *kat* and that *kata* is a derived word with a different meaning. Wiktionary doesn’t have entries for the root words alone, so it has to have the root meaning under the article with the word with an ending. In this case the most logical ending to represent the root meaning of the root *kat* is *kato*.

As always, PMEG has a more detailed [description of this](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/vortfarado/principoj/vortelementoj_signifoj.html#i-mbh).

Answer (score 2):

Linguistics categorizes words into noun, verb and other roots, so `kat` is more noun (`kato`), and `lern` is more verbal (`lerni`).

The number of occurrences of a suffix -o/-i/-a and other statistics play a role.

For Esperanto dictionaries that categorisation could play a role for the entry word:

- **kaso**, kasisto
- **kato**, kateca
- **kavo**
- ...
- **lerni**, lernejo, lernanto

It also has some effects on the word forming:

- **esti alta** = **alti** (rare)
- **esti kato** = *kati* (to be avoided)

The arbitrary roots of different categories:

- **martelo** / **marteli** (=hammer)
- **segi** / **segilo** (=saw)
- **pinĉi** / **pinĉilo**
- though: **ŝraŭbo** / **ŝraŭbi** / **ŝraŭbilo** (=screw / screw driver)

But in general for Esperanto it is an unneeded categorisation.

More sense make *verbal (in)transitivity*.